# anyone knows how to change location in my iphone only for a particular app?(using xcode)

Tags: xcode, location, simulator, gpx

does anyone know how to change location for a particular app? i know about gpx files, but it changes everything.

i want to change the location for an app while still able to use google maps. Is this possible?

Comment: You should describe you environment.  OS, development environment, versions, languages.

Comment: i'm on the latest version of ios and latest version of xcode